# Highstock mysql json compare multiple series

Tags: mysql, json, highcharts

Please help to create a query!
This is a working example of my query Retrieve data as JSON using PHP:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("admin_accounting", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT unix_timestamp(date), sum(ksi2k) FROM accounting where lhc_vo like 'ops' group by year(date), month(date)");
$rows = array();
$rows['type'] = 'area';
$rows['name'] = 'Ops';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $r[0]*1000;
    $rows['data'][] = $r[1];

    array_push($rows);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The JSON results look like this:

```
{"type":"area","name":"Ops","data":[1167664515000,0,1170342915000,0,1172762115000,0,1175436915000,0,1178028915000,0]}
```

But I need the JSON results should look like this:

```
{"type":"area","name":"Ops","data":[[1167664515000,0],[1170342915000,0],[1172762115000,0],[1175436915000,0],[1178028915000,0]]}
```

I would be very grateful for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows['data'][] = array($r[0]*1000, $r[1]);
}
```

Comment: I am appalled by speed, simplicity and elegance of your solutions! Everything works perfectly

Comment: I can only add that the query should be more than one. If the request only one, you have manually close the array.

Comment: @КимКлименко: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but perhaps you simply want to define `$rows['data'] = array();` before the loop?

Comment: Yes, that's right `$result = array();array_push($result,$rows);array_push($result,$rows1);`

Comment: @КимКлименко: You shouldn't need to do any of that `array_push()` stuff at all.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my other answer, you ought to consider switching away from the ancient (and now deprecated, as of PHP v5.5) `ext/mysql`.  Here is an example using PDO, in which you can see how simple your problem becomes:

```
<?php
  $con = new PDO(
    'mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=admin_accounting',
    'user',
    'password'
  );

  $result = $con->query('
    SELECT   1000*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date), SUM(ksi2k)
    FROM     accounting
    WHERE    lhc_vo LIKE "ops"
    GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
  ');

  print json_encode([
    'type' => 'area',
    'name' => 'Ops',
    'data' => $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)
  ]);
?>
```

Note that:

- I have moved the multiplication into the database layer in order that I can simply call [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to obtain the resulting array;
- MySQL will select an indeterminate value from amongst those in each group for the first column in the resultset; should this be undesirable, you will need to apply a suitable aggregate function to the reference to the `date` column; and
- I have used the short array syntax, which is only available from PHP v5.4—if you're using an earlier version, you will need to replace the `[ … ]` of the argument to `json_encode()` with `array( … )`.

Comment: Thank you once again for a qualified full answer.